# SETUP requirements for Google Sheet to connect to a mySQL Server / MS SQL Server

Tags: mysql, google-sheets

I am trying out using Google Sheets to access mySQL Server data to be able to run quick reports / dashboards. While documentation so far points me to whitelist Google IP Addresses... I am not sure if that is all..

my test environment is this:

- mySQL Server on a linux box, with the list of Google IP addresses already white listed ( "iptables -A INPUT  -s IP_ADDRESS -j ACCEPT")
- i tried to setup port forwarding through the main telco router to point to my mySQL Server box (although I am not sure how to test it, since even trying to access mySQL server directly to this box from the WAN seems to be not working)..

I am trying to check with the provider if they also have google ips whitelisted...

Ideally, I should be able to access the mySQL Server from outside the network first.. I am trying to work on that for now...  once I do, I can fairly say that connectivity to my box is working.. therefore Google Sheets should be then able to access my mySQL DB ya?

is this all the setup I need ?  I feel like I'm missing something..

now trying to establish connectivity to mySQL Server from outside that network...

seeking help of telco support for this since the router is setup properly (as far as I know) and yet it seems there is no connectivity..